# How To Change My Array Format In PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date, converters

My code generate array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-05-28
        [1] => 1
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-05-29
        [1] => 1
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-06-02
        [1] => 2
    )
)
```

i want to convert it same as bellow

```
array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 05
        [1] => 2
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 06
        [1] => 2
    )
);
```

how can i convert array like this first month and then total of second value

Comment: Post your original array structure

Comment: edit question  please check

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Please post your expected output, your current output and your current input!

Comment: it's not cleat how final values  (`18`, `20`, `20`) should be produced or from where are they come from

Comment: Even your updation doesn't makes any relevance to your expected output

Comment: Again changed o/p requirement ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract month from `key`, and than check if month in output array exists or not.

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array(
        '2015-05-28',
        1
    ), array(
        '2015-05-29',
        1
    ), array(
        '2015-06-02',
        2
    )
);

$output = array();

foreach ($array as $val) {
    $month = date('m', strtotime($val[0]));

    if (isset($output[$month])) {
        $output[$month] += $val[1];
    } else {
        $output[$month] = $val[1];
    }
}

echo '<pre>';

print_r($output);

/*
    Array
    (
        [05] => 2
        [06] => 2
    )
*/

?>
```

Comment: Hello panther Thanks for reply but can you plz check question again i have some change in qustion

Comment: @vaibhavahalpara: so just use nested `foreach` loop. The main idea is the same.

Answer (score 4):

Really simple solution:

```
foreach($array as $date=>$entry) {
    $month = substr($date, 3, 2); // <-- this requires the date strings to always have the exact same structure
    if(!isset($newArray[$month]))
        $newArray[$month] = 0;
    $newArray[$month] += $entry;
}
```

Comment: Better is to use `date&strtotime` instead of `substr` if we need to parse date.

Comment: In general yes, but substr is definitely faster , and there is no need for that if the structure is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    array(
       '2015-05-28',
        1
    ), 
    array(
       '2015-05-29',
        1
    ), 
    array(
       '2015-06-02',
        2
    )
 );


 $output = array();
 $a=array();
 $b=array();
 foreach ($array as $val) {
    $month = date('m', strtotime($val[0]));
      if (isset($output[$month])) {
            $output[$month] += $val[1];
        } else {
            $output[$month] = $val[1];
        }
      }
      foreach (  $output as $key => $value) {
           $b[] = array($key,$value);
      }
 }
```